# More efficient solution to blackjack?

Tags: java

I'm working on the following problem from codingbat:

> Given 2 int values greater than 0, return whichever value is nearest
>   to 21 without going over. Return 0 if they both go over.
>
> blackjack(19, 21) → 21
>
> blackjack(21, 19) → 21
>
> blackjack(19, 22) → 19

My solutions is:

```
public int blackjack(int a, int b) {
  if (a>21){
    if (b>21){ 
     return 0;
   }
   return b;
  }

  else if(b>21) return a;

  return Math.max(a,b);
}
```

Is there something in my logic that can be improved to make it more efficient?  Am I doing something unnecessary?

Comment: You shouldn't worry about efficiency on such a tiny, tiny function

Comment: what if he's going to be playing a *lot* of blackjack?

Comment: In python I've found that with 2 numbers using if statements is more efficient than using max.  I.e. If A>B return a else return B.

Comment: `return a < 22 && b < 22 ? a < b ? b : a : a < 22 ? a : b < 22 ? b : 0;` ;)

Answer (score 4):

This *could* be more efficient.  At the very least it's another way of looking at the problem:

```
public int blackjack(int a, int b) {
  if (a>21) a = 0;
  if (b>21) b = 0;

  if (a>b) {
    return a;
  else {
    return b;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 to you but... I think people modifying Java method parameters should be shot  (I also happen to think that Java creators should be shot for not mandating *final* on method parameters).  But that's because I love functional programming and immutability and because I'm facetious too ; )

Comment: We could instead do 'if (a>21) return blackjack(0, b);' ;)

Comment: It does get cleaner, but will declaring variables start to make it less efficient?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say this is more efficient, but I re-ordered some of the if statements and arrived at the code below. I think this is, at the very least, somewhat easier to follow:

```
public int blackjack(int a, int b) {
  if (a <= 21 && b <= 21) return Math.max(a, b);
  if (a <= 21) return a;
  if (b <= 21) return b;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using ternary operator:

```
public int blackjack(int a, int b) {
    a = a > 21 ? 0 : a;
    b = b > 21 ? 0 : b;
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be pretty close;

`public int blackjack(int a, int b) {
        if(a > 21 && b > 21) return 0;
        else if (a <= 21 && a > b || b > 21) return a;
        return b;
    }`